# Missing network adapter advanced properties in Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I have an older desktop PC running Windows 10 that I've recently set up with a wireless network card. Motherboard is a [GIGABYTE GA-990XA-UD3 AM3+](http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B0055QYKQ4). As far as I can tell it should be able to fully utilize my wifi card. See below I also tried with a much newer rig and got the same behavior.

[Wireless AC Dual Band AC1200 (2.4GHz 300Mbps or 5GHz 867Mbps) PCIE Wi-Fi Adapter](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07JJFYG7J).

Despite my best efforts, I am having trouble getting strong Internet speeds (they are usually in the 10-15mb/s range). I don't believe it has anything to do with my distance from the router or the like. Instead, one hig clue is that I am missing some expected device manager advanced properties that others who use this card have referenced when describing steps to troubleshoot. These advanced properties, if I had them, would let me set the wifi protocol to 802.11n or 802.11ac, or change bandwidth settings from 10MB, to 100Mb or 1000MB. But they are simply not appearing in the advanced properties dialog for my wifi card.

So my main question is: **Why don't I have these Device Manager Advanced Properties for my wifi card?**

Here is what I see:

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

I worked directly with the vendor to make sure I had the right driver, and have uninstalled/reinstalled numerous times hoping to see these missing Device Manager properties that should help me properly configure this card. Ultimately the vendor returned my money with an apology that I was not able to get it working as expected.

I also installed this card with the vendor-provided driver on my main desktop rig (much more recent build) and saw no difference in available Device Manager properties. This suggests to me that it's not an issue of an older motherboard that perhaps can't support this wifi card completely.

I'm wondering if there are any additional steps I can take to uncover the expected properties for configuration? Could this behavior actually be a hardware issue with the card, where it works but not to it's full capacity? Or is the availability of Device Manager properties 100% a driver issue, so that's what I need to sort out?

Answer (score 1):

Can you go to Control Panel and search "network connections" and then click view network connections and then on your wifi adapter, right click and click status and check the speed. It should be around 54mbps as you are connected to your router via 802.11g which has a max speed of 54mbps.

I'd also check if your router supports 802.11n or even 802.11ac because if it does then you may need to split your 5GHz and 2.4GHz bands

EDIT:

I also have a Qualcomm wireless controller and have similar options to what you have, I think what you are seeing is normal in terms of options.

Comment: Thanks Jadi for the response. I do see 54Mbps in the connection status screen, for running at 11g. My router is pretty serious and I'm can support 802.11n and ac. NETGEAR Nighthawk X4S Smart WiFi Router (R7800) - AC2600.

Comment: I did also mess with my router a bit, but I think the missing properties are the bigger issue.

One of the top reviews for this wifi card mentions the Device Manager Advanced Properties that needed to be adjusted, and so many other references I've come across while troubleshooting note many more options available there than I see. Maybe we're both missing out!

Comment: Sorry for not responding, I didn't check my emails haha. On your router you might want to try and split your 5ghz and 2.4ghz bands into two different ssid's and then just connect to your 5ghz. Your wifi adapter is probably defaulting to the 2.4ghz band for some reason so by splitting the SSID's you can force it to use your AC wifi.

Comment: No problem, Jadi. Pretty sure I had tried that while messing with my router settings, but I did it again to double-check. I simply get an error "Can't connect to this network" when trying the 5ghz.

Comment: I purchased another wifi card, based on an Intel chipset. It provided a bunch more network adaptor advanced properties, including the kinds of things I was expecting to see with the first card like actual b/g/n/ac options. With this new card I CAN use the 5ghz network, but it only connects using 802.11a, which gets me around the same speeds I saw previously. Even though my router supports 802.11ac protocol, and both cards claim to support 802.11ac as well, I've still never seen this protocol being used. I guess this suggests that it's something on my end, but I do not know what that could be.